# Difference between python thread start_new_thread and using celery and which one is good for async task for django

Tags: python, celery, python-multithreading

I am writing an script to send email and render a page in django. I have seen email sending code in start_new_thread works asynchronously.

Comment: you are mixing way too many concepts here.

Comment: what is the good way to send email asynchronously

Comment: Celery is a job queue. As such it limits the number of concurrently running jobs and keep records of jobs yet uncompleted to run later, and jobs can continue running uninterrupted when you have to restart your web server, and jobs can be ran on other machines. You get none of that if you just start threads.